# Merging data frames with partial Matching using R

Tags: r

Lets say I have data frame df1 with the following variables

```
Continent   Country
1   Europe  Russia
2   Asia    Myanmar (Burma)
3   africa  Benin
4   africa  Botswana
5   africa  Burkina
```

and df2 with the following variables

```
Continent   Country
1   Europe  Russian Federation
2   Asia    Myanmar
3   africa  Benin,new
4   africa  Botswana
5   africa  Burkina
```

How do I combine the 2 df together by Country using partial matching

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and show what you have already tried...this way you can help others to help you!

Answer (score 2):

You can merge on the first five characters.  You will need to install the `stringr` package

replicating your data

```
a<- data.frame( Continent=c("Europe","Asia","africa","africa","africa"), Country=c("Russia","Myanmar (Burma)","Benin","Botswana","Burkina"))
b <- data.frame( Continent=c("Europe","Asia","africa","africa","africa"), Country=c("Russian Federation","Myanmar","Benin,new","Botswana","Burkina"))
```

create a variable taking the lower case first five letters

```
 a$key <- stringr::str_extract(tolower(a$Country), "\\b[a-z]{0,5}")
 b$key <- stringr::str_extract(tolower(b$Country), "\\b[a-z]{0,5}")
```

and then merge on the new key (you will probably want to rename your cols before this merge

```
  merge( a , b , by="key")
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to know what you final/desired data frame would look like.

You could consider the `fuzzyjoin` package in merging these two data frames. One approach would be to use `str_detect` and see if one `Country` string is contained in the other.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

mf <- function(a, b) str_detect(a, b) | str_detect(b, a)

fuzzy_semi_join(df1, df2, by = "Country", match_fun = mf)

  Continent         Country
1    Europe          Russia
2      Asia Myanmar (Burma)
3    Africa           Benin
4    Africa        Botswana
5    Africa         Burkina
```

An inner join will should you how the rows are matched (keeping both `Country` columns for comparison):

```
fuzzy_inner_join(df1, df2, by = "Country", match_fun = mf)

  Continent.x       Country.x Continent.y          Country.y
1      Europe          Russia      Europe Russian Federation
2        Asia Myanmar (Burma)        Asia            Myanmar
3      Africa           Benin      Africa          Benin,new
4      Africa        Botswana      Africa           Botswana
5      Africa         Burkina      Africa            Burkina
```